# Extension of the "stars and bars" method?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, uniform-distribution

**Question**

Ten apples are to be distributed among three people without restriction.

(a)$\quad$ What is the probability that one person receives all ten apples if each way of distributing the apples is equally likely?

(b)$\quad$ What is the probability that one person receives all ten apples if each apple is distributed uniformly at random?

(c)$\quad$ Why are the two answers so different?

**My working**

(a)$\quad$ If each way of distributing the apples is equally likely, then the required probability is $$\frac {\binom {3} 1} {\binom {12} 2},$$ where the numerator comes from the fact that there are only three ways to distribute all ten apples to a single person (i.e. just choose one of the three people) and the denominator comes from the total number of ways to distribute all ten apples without restriction.

---

Is my reasoning for part (a) correct? Moreover, I have no clue as to how I should approach (b) and (c). Any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second problem, the first apple has a one-third chance of going to person $A$ as it is distributed uniformly at random. The same is true for all the apples. Therefore, the chance that $A$ receives every apple is just $\frac 1 {3^{10}}$. $B$ or $C$ have the same chance to get all of them, giving $3\times \frac{1}{3^{10}}=\frac{1}{3^9}$.

To understand the difference, look at the following game: $A$ tosses coins. Heads gives $+1$ and tails gives $-1$. In two tosses, he can be $+2,-2$ or $0$. Problem 1 asks us to consider all these states as equally likely. Therefore, the probability is $1/3$ for each. However, in Problem 2, the probability is $1/4$ for the first two and $1/2$ for the last one because the states are not, in reality, equally likely.